# Visual Studio 2010 PowerCommands extension missing in options dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powercommands

I downloaded and installed the *PowerCommands.vsix* extension for Visual Studio 2010.

But then, under Tools->Options there is no entry for the extension.

Visual Studio says that it is correctly installed in the Extension Manager.

Do you know where to find the tools?

Many thanks, Juergen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found these links:

[social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vssetup/thread/f3aab63d-23ea-4ca5-9cf0-14aab6dea310)

[connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595437/my-vs-2010-extension-manager-is-gone)

So it seems that this is a serious problem that may occur.
In my case only a clean reinstallation of VS2010 fixed the problem.